# Jmeter unale to login to SAML application

Tags: jmeter

I have done some research on how to do SAML login but I cannot.  I am getting following error-

www.abc.com/samlidp/saml/SSOService?SAMLRequest=%24%7BSAMLRequest%7D&RelayState=${RelayState}

[image]

where am I going wrong?

Comment: Make sure your Regex or Path Extractor is working correctly. Add a `Debug Sampler` and `View Response in Tree` Listener to view it.

Comment: where is the error details??